# Evento Ng-click dinámico, ¿posible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

para empezar estoy usando angular 1.6.6

Estoy tratando de crear una modal dinámica, la cual se puede llenar y completar desde controladores angular, todo funciona bien, la modal esta relacionada con los otros controladores mediante $controller

```
//Instancia del controlador resize
$controller('otherController', {
    $scope: $scope
});
```

Esto es para que las funciones $scope se puedan ejecutar desde el controlador de la modal.

en la modal tengo un botón, este botón le creo un atributo **ng-click** mediante un servicio de angular y le añado el nombre de la función que quiere ejecutar y re compilo la etiqueta para que angular reconozca el atributo ng-click

```
$closeModalBtn.setAttribute('ng-click', 'function()');
this.compile($closeModalBtn);
```

La función se ejecuta bien pero si vuelvo a llenar la modal dinámica con otra función al momento de darle click se ejecuta la nueva función 1 vez, luego 3, luego 6 y así sucesivamente, se que el error esta en la compilación del elemento DOM pero si quito la compilación angular no reconocería ningún ng-click.

Comment: No sería mejor pasar algún tipo de parámetro al `ng-click` y dependiendo de el valor de ese parámetro llamar a la función correspondiente?

Comment: No, ya que la idea de la modal es poder llamar cualquier función sin tener que crear una configuración para cada una de ella.

Comment: Es que no tendrías que realizar configuraciones extras... ya que podrías tener una función padre que a través de un parámetro a definir por ti, manejarías con un `switch` por ejemplo y llamarías a las funciones que necesites

Comment: eso es exactamente lo que quiero evitar, agregar un case por cada función, es decir, 10 o 15 funciones esta bien pero al momento de llamar mas funciones ya no seria tan funcional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta bien, resolví este problema ya que con la compilación de angular el elemento siempre almacenaba el evento anterior (que en este caso es la función anterior) y agregaba además el evento actual (la función actual) esto hacia que al dar click en el evento se ejecutaran todas las funciones que estaban relacionadas con este elemento.

como angular no nos deja ver los eventos de los elementos, la mejor solución que pude encontrar fue eliminar el botón que tenia el evento como tal y creándolo nuevamente.

Esto hace que el evento con el que esta relacionado el elemento que eliminamos de igual forma desaparezca. y al crearlo desde cero se toma como un elemento nuevo sin eventos.

```
$parentBtn = document.getElementById('padre de boton');

while ($parentBtn.firstChild)
{
   //se elimina todos los elementos del padre
   $parentBtn.removeChild($parentBtn.firstChild);
}

//Se crea un boton 
$newButton = document.createElement('button');
$newButton.id = "childId";
$newButton.type = "button";
$newButton.className = $button.class;
$newButton.innerHTML = $button.text;
$newButton.setAttribute('ng-click', $button.function);

//se agrega el nuevo elemento        
$parentBtn.appendChild($newButton);

//Se compila para reconoces funciones angular
this.compile($newButton);
```

Suerte!!!.